# On Button Click, how do I change row with span to input and focus each input using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a table, with 2 labels/inputs (i use a ng-show/ng-hide which works with the edit button), and 2 buttons (1 button is edit, and 1 button is delete).  What i want to do is when the user clicks the edit button, it should hide the spans and shows the inputs(textboxes) and focus on the first input.  If the user clicks outside of either inputs, (in my opinion, loses focus which mean using blur method), then the inputs should turn back to span with the updated values.  Here is what I have created, but I can't figure out the rest.  New to angular so any help will be appreciated and voted.

This is the html code:

```
<table class="tableGV">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="DisplayRowData">
                <span class="LabelText" data-ng-hide="data1">{{data1}}</span>
                <input class="DataText" type="text"data-ng-show="showEditMode" maxLength="1" data-ng-model="editData1" ng-change="cs.ClassCode"/>
           </td>
           <td class="DisplayRowData">
               <span class="LabelText" data-ng-hide="data2">{{data2}}</span>
               <input class="DataText" type="text" data-ng-show="data2" maxlength="50" data-ng-model="data2" />
           </td>
           <td align="right">
               <button type="button" id = "btnEditClassService{{$index}}" data-ng-click="edit(cs, $index)" class="editButton"></button>
               <button type="button" id = "btnDeleteClassService{{$index}}" data-ng-click="delete(cs, $index)" class="deleteButton"></button>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

after this, i am not sure where to go.  Thanks for anyone to help me.

Comment: Can you please show your JavaScript code as well?

Comment: Hey, my script code is just like the first response I got in the answer section.  I do have one question though, why is it that I can't get the active element after the timeout has executed.  When I try to run this, nothing shows up for the active element.

Comment: function onEdit(){
      vm.isEdit =  true;
      executeAfterDOMRender(function(){
        document.getElementById('txt1').focus()
      });
      console.log("This is active element: " + document.activeElement.id);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/kBd1Ni?p=info). The solution is not elegant but I think it sastify your requirement.

```
function onEdit(){
  vm.isEdit =  true;
  executeAfterDOMRender(function(){
    document.getElementById('txt1').focus()
  });
}

function onBlur(){
  executeAfterDOMRender(function(){
    var txtIds = ['txt1', 'txt2'];
    var activeElementId = document.activeElement.id;
    if(~txtIds.indexOf(activeElementId)){
      //txt boxes is focued, do nothing here
    } else {
      vm.isEdit = false;
    }
  });
}

function executeAfterDOMRender(callback){
  $timeout(callback);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I have a quick question though.  If your onEdit method.  You set the row to true to show the inputs.  Then you use timeout which I get.  But after the timeout, if I write console.log(document.activeElement) it returns nothing, can you explain that to me please.  Otherwise this is great.

Comment: I've never experience in document.activeElement = null before. I tried to print it out but in my machine, it always print out the input/body/button :-?

Comment: Oh ok.  So here is my logic.  When the edit button is clicked, and it switches from span to input, in JS, you set a timeout to also execute the focus command.  You are right (I was wrong) document.activeElement does not print out null, it prints out the HTML TableCollection which consists of the buttons (edit and delete).  I thought that because the cursor is focusing the input box, that when we log the active element, because the cursor is in the input box, that is what the active element is.  But no worries, your code helped me out so much.  Thank you very much.  You are awesome!!!